# Open menu on hover instead of click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, mouseevent

I want to change the default Bootstrap navbar component to a drilldown navigation on mobile.
Do do that, I've added some JavaScript code to change my menu.

Here's the code I'm using at the moment: https://codepen.io/cray_code/pen/dENeKM

It works fine but on desktop the menu opens after a click instead an hover event.

For the desktop viewport there is the following code:

```
$('.mega-menu-trigger').bind('click' ,function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var current = $(this).next('.mega-menu');
    $('.mega-menu-trigger').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.mega-menu').not(current).removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
    if( !current.hasClass('open') ){
        current.removeClass('closed').addClass('open');
    } else {
        current.removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
    }
});
```

I tried to change the code with `mouseenter` to this:

```
$('.mega-menu-trigger').bind(mouseenter: function(e){
```

But that doesn't work and I have the problem that the menu stays open after leaving the link.
I guess I have to work with `mouseleave` but I couldn't figure out how.

Is there any way to change the menu from click to hover?

Comment: Can't you use css to do this?

Comment: I tried that. But could figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menu open close behavior on hover can be achieved using a combination of mouseenter and mouseleave events in the follwoing way.

```
// Klick Funktionen hinzufÃ¼gen
$('.mega-menu-trigger').bind('mouseenter mouseleave' ,function(e){

   e.preventDefault();
   var current = $(this).next('.mega-menu');
   $('.mega-menu-trigger').not(this).removeClass('active');
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
   $('.mega-menu').not(current).removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
   if( !current.hasClass('open') ){
      current.removeClass('closed').addClass('open');
   } else {
     current.removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
   }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't see any logic for closing the menu in my code. Where do I have to add that?

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as you said...you need to work with mouseenter and mouseleave...simply do this.

```
$('.mega-menu-trigger').bind('mouseenter mouseleave' ,function(e){
```

Answer (score 1):

Css code that works with your code in codepen:

```
.menu-item.has-sub-menu:hover > .menu > .menu-item{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    opacity: 1!important;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s .6s ease-in-out, margin .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .3s .6s ease-in-out, margin .6s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code

```
$('.mega-menu-trigger').hover(function (e){

                e.preventDefault();
                var current = $(this).next('.mega-menu');
                $('.mega-menu-trigger').not(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
                $('.mega-menu').not(current).removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
                if( !current.hasClass('open') ){
                    current.removeClass('closed').addClass('open');
                } else {
                    current.removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
                }
            });
```

this will open menu on hover

here is fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/w4vmyrpz/